# How to create login form to access private area

Tags: php, authentication

I have a client that wants users to access a private area on their HTML website to download resources.

Just wanted your advice on what the best solution would be to set this up.

My knowledge in PHP is pretty poor.

We have also spoke about moving their website over to a CMS such as wordpress. Would this be easier to do with Wordpress via a plugin, or is it just as easy to implement on a static HTML site?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case the easiest way would be createing a htpasswd file.

Put `.htaccess` file inside a directory you wish to be private and write:

```
AuthUserFile /real/path/to/file/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secreat place"
require valid-user
```

and in `.htpasswd` write the user and **crypted** password:

```
admin:$apr1$nOq27Mwz$xnM1lIqrwyvbBmp0V/.TJ1
```

PS: This stands for the password *admin*

Comment: PS: You can generate passwords using this tool: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: I think expanding on how to create the .htpasswd file would be helpful, e.g. something like this: http://www.colostate.edu/~ric/htpass.html or the generator you linked to in your comment

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many many things. I suggest you google for `user authentication php` and choose the best solution for your needs. And then if you got into trouble implementing it, ask on Stack.